# Filtering for values in Pivot table columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I wanted to aggregate values/sum a column by a certain time period, how do I do it using the pivot table? For example in the table below, if I want the aggregate sum of fruits between 2000 - 2001, and 2002 - 2004, what code would I write? Currently I have this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


UG = pd.read_csv('fruitslist.csv', index_col=2)
UG = UG.pivot_table(values = 'Count', index = 'Fruits', columns = 'Year', aggfunc=np.sum)
UG.to_csv('fruits.csv')
```

This returns counts for each fruit by each individual year, but I can't seem to aggregate by decade (e.g 90s, 00s, 2010s)

```
Fruits    Count   Year

Apple     4       1995

Orange    5       1996

Orange    6       2001

Guava     8       2003

Banana    6       2010

Guava     8       2011

Peach     7       2012

Guava     9       2013
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a sample(few rows) of your input dataframe?

Comment: Do you need to use `.pivot_table`? Would a `groupby` suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the reply all.                                                                                 
1st comment - The above sample is what I was hoping would be enough. Thats basically the table format I am using. Second Comment - Yes, a group by would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. Convert the `Year` column within a `groupby` to decades and then aggregate.

```
"""
Fruits    Count   Year

Apple     4       1995

Orange    5       1996

Orange    6       2001

Guava     8       2003

Banana    6       2010

Guava     8       2011

Peach     7       2012

Guava     9       2013
"""

df = pd.read_clipboard()

output = df.groupby([
    df.Year//10*10,
    'Fruits'
]).agg({
    'Count' : 'sum'
})

print(output)

             Count
Year Fruits       
1990 Apple       4
     Orange      5
2000 Guava       8
     Orange      6
2010 Banana      6
     Guava      17
     Peach       7
```

---

### Edit

If you want to group the years by a different amount, say every 2 years, just change the Year group:

```
print(df.groupby([
    df.Year//2*2,
    'Fruits'
]).agg({
    'Count' : 'sum'
}))

             Count
Year Fruits       
1994 Apple       4
1996 Orange      5
2000 Orange      6
2002 Guava       8
2010 Banana      6
     Guava       8
2012 Guava       9
     Peach       7
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


UG = pd.read_csv('fruitslist.csv', index_col=2)

UG = UG.query('Year >= 1990 and Year <= 2000')
                                                          
UG = UG.groupby(['Fruits'])['Count'].sum()
  
                                                                               
This was another method I was trying to use. But I was unable to add more year/decade ranges using the query line - e.g 2000-2010 Is there a way to do that?              Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MS.TO please consider selecting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @MS.TO For your second comment I suggest asking a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. For a short answer, your code doesnt' allow you to see more than one decade because you filtered it to a single decade before the `groupby`.